# How to create abstract model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am new to Django framework and in my project I have a model called Layer.

```
class Layer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I would like layer to have a relationship with an abstract model called "Geometry", more specifically, one layer should have one or no Geometry and one Geometry should be owned by one layer.

The problem is that I have for types of Geometries and they all have different properties, so I decided to create multiple geometries:

```
class Circle(models.Model):
    radius = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Rectangle(models.Model):
    height = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I would like to have a data structure where both models are of the same type (Geometry). I would like to call layer.geometry and be able to get either a circle or a rectangle, or a cross and so on. Is that possible? And how is the database shape going to be like? Is Django going to create two different tables or one table with merged properties?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can not have a relation with an *abstract* model. You can subclass it, but the model will still have a table. This should be done to introduce `FOREIGN KEY` constraints to prevent referring to a non-existing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django supports inheritance, although it is not very common. You can thus create a model `Geometry`, and let `Circle` and `Rectangle` inherit from that:

```
class Geometry(models.Model):
    pass

class Circle(Geometry):
    radius = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Rectangle(Geometry):
    height = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

We can furthermore make a `ForeignKey` (or another relation) to this `Geometry` class with:

```
class Layer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    geometry = models.ForeignKey(Geometry, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Django will make migrations that, for an SQL database create tables for `Geometry`, `Circle` and `Rectangle`. The `Circle` and `Rectangle` models will have an implicit `OneToOneRelation` to the table for the `Geometry` named `geometry_ptr_id`, that thus refers to the parent.

For more information, see the section on [*Multi-table inheritance* in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).

Comment: Right, perfectly explained. Django allows abstract classes but you cannot refer to them.

Comment: Does that mean that I cannot run layer.geometry? Not even in the json response of the django-rest-framework? So if a layer has a circle, it will be called circle not geometry?

Answer (score 0):

Although you can link `Cirle` and `Rectangle` models with `ForeignKey` or `OneToOneField`, your have an option to create an `AbstractModel` for `Geometry` model.

```
class Geometry(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Circle(Geometry):
    radius = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Rectangle(Geometry):
    height = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    width = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

As such, both `Circle` and `Rectangle` models will have id field from `Geometry` model, but will only have 2 tables in your database. However, you wont be able to query in `Geometry` model.

If you need to query explicitly for `Geometry` model, go for `ForeignKey` or `OneToOneField` option. If not, `abstract` model is a cleaner approach in my opinion.

[From Django Docs:](http://Often,%20you%20will%20just%20want%20to%20use%20the%20parent%20class%20to%20hold%20information%20that%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20want%20to%20have%20to%20type%20out%20for%20each%20child%20model.%20This%20class%20isn%E2%80%99t%20going%20to%20ever%20be%20used%20in%20isolation,%20so%20Abstract%20base%20classes%20are%20what%20you%E2%80%99re%20after.) Often, you will just want to use the parent class to hold information that you don’t want to have to type out for each child model. This class isn’t going to ever be used in isolation, so Abstract base classes are what you’re after.